# How to fit WebView size with its content

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, macos, webview

I just wanna fit the WebView of a macOS application with its content, which contain some scripts. I tried it by using

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];`

but it gives the size of the WebView with just plain html.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using MathJax to render math equations from LaTeX code, and MathJax is javascript so that's why I'm using a webview. I just want to obtain the frame of these equations to fit them in the webview. I noticed that when click on the equations these are bounded by a blue outline (from accessibility), I don't know if there is a way to obtain the frame of this outline..